# Android; SQLite database Cursor is null. It should not be. I don't know why it is

Tags: android-cursor, sqlite

I had a method which fetched records from an sqlite database but after a while i changed it a little and made a secondary method for fetching specific records with user entered information.

I don't know why but my original method is returning null now.

CardDbAdapter:

```
public CarddbAdapter open2() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDatabaseR = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        myDatabaseW = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        return this;
    }

public void MyDatabaseClose() {
        myDatabaseW.close();
        myDatabaseR.close();
    }

public ArrayList<String> getAllCardNames() {
        ArrayList<String> returnedAllCardNames;
        ArrayList<String> NoResults;
        ArrayList<String> NoResults2;
        NoResults = new ArrayList<String>();
        NoResults.add("cursor is null");
        NoResults2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        NoResults2.add("No similar cards found.");
        returnedAllCardNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        /*String sqlquery_cardNames = "SELECT " + KEY_CARDNAME
                + " FROM cards WHERE card_name like '%" + passedName
                + "%' ORDER BY card_name ASC";*/
        //String sqlquery_cardNames;
        String sqlquery_cardNames = "SELECT DISTINCT card_name FROM cards";
        Cursor c_cardNames;
        c_cardNames = myDatabaseW.rawQuery(sqlquery_cardNames, null);

        c_cardNames.moveToFirst();
        if (c_cardNames != null) {
            do {
                if (c_cardNames.getCount() > 0) {
                    String returnedName = c_cardNames.getString(c_cardNames
                            .getColumnIndex(KEY_CARDNAME));
                    returnedAllCardNames.add(returnedName);
                } else {
                    return NoResults2;
                }
            } while (c_cardNames.moveToNext());
        }
        return NoResults;
    }
```

How i am using it:

```
CarddbAdapter yugiohDB = new CarddbAdapter(this);

yugiohDB.open2();

                search_results = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSearchResults);
                search_results.setOnItemClickListener(this);

                ArrayList<String> returnedCards_list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                returnedCards_list1.addAll(yugiohDB.getAllCardNames());

                listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchMode_Simple.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, returnedCards_list1);
                search_results.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                yugiohDB.MyDatabaseClose();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

If you would like to see what this is actually supposed to do then download my app called Yugioh Library + Tools. Click the Search Library button from the main menu and then the button Simple Search. It should be displaying a list of cards from the database.

The reason i was changing it is because i'm setting up Spinners so users can choose different trading card sets to choose some which would then list all the cards from that specific set.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I forgot to return the string array "returnedAllCardNames" which was holding the names of all process card records after the do while loop.